# Array average calculation

Tags: java, arrays

Cannot find why my array in the class aint working. Not sure if maybe static has something to do with the problem. I receive alot of errors but i think the main one is "cannot make a static ref to the non-static field rej"

MAIN:

```
public class Arajmain {
public static void main (String[]args){

    System.out.println(Araj.genomsnittet());


}
}
```

CLASS

```
public class Araj {

double [] rej = new double[3];
public static double genomsnitt;

rej[0] = 4;
rej[1] = 7;
rej[2] = 9;

public static double genomsnittet(){
    genomsnitt = (rej[0] + rej[1] + rej[2])/3;
    return genomsnitt;
}   
}
```

Comment: It *isn't* (not "ain't") working because it won't compile. You have statements that aren't in a constructor, method, or initializer block. You need to put the lines adding values to `rej` in a static initializer block (because you've made it `static`), or make them part of an initializer on the declaration line.

Comment: Just a recommendation, consider changing `/3` to `/rej.length` for maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Araj {
  private static double [] rej = new double[3];
  static {
    rej[0] = 4;
    rej[1] = 7;
    rej[2] = 9;
  }
  public static double genomsnittet(){
    double genomsnitt = (rej[0] + rej[1] + rej[2])/3;
    return genomsnitt;
  }   
}
```

That's some piece of ugly code though. You should definetly have a look at a tutorial about Java and OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `static` modifier to `reg`:

```
static double [] rej = new double[3];
```

Also, you can initialize it using a static initialization block:

```
static {
   rej[0] = 4;
   rej[1] = 7;
   rej[2] = 9;
}
```

Or using using a more concise array literal:

```
static double [] rej = new double[]{4, 7, 9};
```

Answer (score -1):

This is quite terrible code, anyway to make it work you should have "rej" declared as static.

EDIT: As already suggested, you should also initalize it properly :

```
static {
   rej[0] = 4;
   rej[1] = 7;
   rej[2] = 9;
}
```

Comment: This won't fix the problem. The initialization lines for the elements of `rej` are not in a valid location.

Comment: Yeah that's true. Sorry